# Tinylog Android, VerifyError exception

Tags: android, tinylog

After updating tinylog to version **2.5.0-M1.1 \ 2.5.0-M2**, On **Android 4.4 API 19** Started throwing VerifyError exceptions as soon as *ThreadContext.put()* or *org.tinylog.Logger.tag()* is called. On other versions of android everything is fine

Translation to version **2.4.1** helps. But I need to use DynamicPolicy

I did not find the minimum version of the API in the documentation. From the application side, I could not get around the exception. Can you please tell me if this can be fixed or version **2.5** is not supported on **android 4.4**?

Here is the full exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.wsoft.push.sample, PID: 6609
java.lang.VerifyError: org/tinylog/configuration/JndiValueResolver
    at org.tinylog.configuration.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:64)
    at org.tinylog.provider.ProviderRegistry.loadLoggingProvider(ProviderRegistry.java:87)
    at org.tinylog.provider.ProviderRegistry.<clinit>(ProviderRegistry.java:39)
    at org.tinylog.ThreadContext.<clinit>(ThreadContext.java:32)
    at ru.wings.push.sdk.logging.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at ru.wings.push.sdk.logging.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at ru.wings.push.sdk.logging.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at e.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at e.a.$r8$lambda$a3WCZYd0yZju55XeNNLHv5MIHVY(Unknown Source)
    at e.a$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onComplete(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
enter code here
```

Comment: The minimum Android API version is 1.0 for tinylog 2. The JndiValueResolver should not be loaded on Android. This is a bug in the tinylog 2.5 milestones.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Can you tell me if this will be fixed soon?

Comment: I have just committed a fix (https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog/commit/caebd106e1d3ed06d0be5d2fdeb90528b49e92de). tinylog 2.5.0-M2.1 will be released during the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is fixed in tinylog 2.5.0-M2.1: https://tinylog.org/v2/2022/06/update-for-second-milestone-2/

Thank you for reporting this bug! Please test this version and let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix! On all my devices it began to work without crashes!